# C# Login data of Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am developing a windows service and I want to get the context in which it is executed. By context I mean the user account in which it is executed.
I tried to work with the WindowsIdentity but I am not getting the value I am expecting.

```
    string exception = "";
    try
    {
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        // I wonder what to do here...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //store the exception until the logging is initialized
        exception = ex.ToString();
        i_UserLevel = 0;
    }
```

Background is that I want to log the context in which the service is executed so that I can log what is happening and maybe handle the code at some points differently when the service is not allowed to, so that I don't have to fill up everything with try...catch

So the question is how do I get the user account associated with the service ?
for example: administrator or localsystem account.

Comment: What is the value you are expecting and what is the value you are receiving?

Comment: I am expecting for example administrator or localsystem account. What I am getting depends on the values I am asking of the identity variable. But its mostly numbers.

Comment: identity.Name should be what you're looking for

Comment: Unless your service performs impersonation, all of `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`, `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` and the account displayed in the `Services` control panel should be matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `identity.Name`. For localsystem account it's value is `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. A little code to test it could look something like this:

```
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            try
            {
                System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                sw.Write(identity.Name);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sw.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                sw.Flush(); sw.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Your code works but I guess my question was wrong. I am getting the names in German (I am from germany) but our software may run on english systems to. I was expecting english user groups . I will have to write another question I guess

Comment: okay found the answer through this answer .                     identity.IsSystem;
identity.IsAuthenticated;